# How to get notified when new clients are connected on my LAN?

Tags: security, notifications, network-monitoring

Is there any solution which can allow me to store MAC's and IP's of my clients and notify me via email whenever a new one is connected? (Preferably for Windows)

*I know I can script it myself but looking for a ready made solution.*

Comment: Hello! Questions that are requests for products that do "X" are considered off-topic for SU. Voting to close as such...

Answer (score -1):

It's called DHCP server and as you said you can script that yourself by parsing dhcp logs. I am not aware of an out of the box solution but I am sure  something like spiceworks can do it with minimum setup

http://www.spiceworks.com/